# solve convert problem from one entity to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
var i = SectionRepository.GetAll().OrderBy(x => x.Name).GroupBy(x => x.Category).OrderBy(x => x.Key.Name);
 var b = (IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<TaggedEntity, TaggedEntity>>)i;
```

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[Prj.Core.Domain.Category,Prj.Core.Domain.Section],System.String]'
>   to type
>   'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[Prj.Core.Common.TaggedEntity,Prj.Core.Common.TaggedEntity]]'.

Hi all. Help me pls. Section and Category inherited from TaggedEntity. Error occurs during conversion.
Project is using .net 4 and asp mvc 4. How i can convert this entities?

Comment: Please, share the rest of code and your entities

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert a child class to its parent class.

You need to use some kind of interface for the parent class, e.g.

```
public interface ITaggedItem {
    string Tag {get;set;}
}

public class TaggedItem: ITaggedItem {
    public string Tag {get;set;}
}

public class Category: TaggedItem{
}

var b = (IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<ITaggedEntity, ITaggedEntity>>)i;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to case `Category` or `Section` to `TaggedEntity`, because both are derived from it, but `IGrouping<Category, Section>` and `IGrouping<TaggedEntity, TaggedEntity>` are totally different types.
Instead cast every value explicitly, before building expected collection

```
var orderedGroups = SectionRepository.GetAll()
    .OrderBy(section => section.Name)
    .GroupBy(section => (TaggedEntity)section.Category, section => (TaggedEntity)section)
    .OrderBy(group => group.Key.Name); // Hope "Name" is the part of TaggedEntity type
```